# No guarda dos llaves foráneas de un formulario

Tags: php, sql, html5, pdo

```
<?php
require_once('conexion.php');
$conn = new conexion();
$llamarMetodo = $conn->Conectar()
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_ciudades_municipios";
$envie = $llamarMetodo->prepare($sql);
$envie->execute();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registar ubicaciones</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<body>
    <div>
    <center>
        <font size="99" face="verdana">
        <form action ="registrar_ubicaciones.php" method="POST" style="width: 333px; height: 450px; background: red">
        <input type = "text" name = "direccion" placeholder = "la direccion aquí"><br>
        <select name = "tbl_ciudades_municipios_id_ciudad_municipio">
            <option> seleccione el municipio o la ciudad</option>
            <?php
            while($r= $envie->fetch()){
                    echo '<option value ="'.$r[0].'">'.$r[1].'</option>';
            }             
        ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="Registrate" value="Registrar">
        </form>
        </font>
    </center>   
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deberias explicar mejor que es lo que sucede, cual es el error y como quieres que quede el resultado, se mas explicito

Comment: Disculpa tienes toda la razón soy nuevo en stackoverflow, lo que sucede es que tengo un formulario en el cual se deben seleccionar dos llaves foráneas, tambin ingresar dos datos, ingreso todo bien pero en el momento de enviar no presenta ningún fallo, voy y reviso en la base de datos y no encuentro ningún registro en la tabla. tengo mas formularios y funcionan perfectamente.

Comment: Ok, es natural, Bienvenido bro, te invito a que te des un paseo por [https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour] y asi aprendes sobre como preguntar y de paso ganas tus primeras medallas... ReNiceCode...

Comment: edita tu pregunta y pon el archivo `registrar_ubicaciones.php` en el cual capturas los valores del formulario, por otro lado, y hizo pruebas directamente en la BD ? el select te muestra bien los datos ?

Comment: No comprendo bien tu problema. Deberías poner el archivo registrar_ubicaciones.php para ver el procesamiento. Veo que te falta un ; después de conectar().